# How do I pause apt upgrade before putting the laptop to sleep? How would I resume it when I open it again?

Tags: command-line, apt, upgrade

I need to pause the program now so that I can resume it at home. How can I do that?

Comment: Don't pause upgrade!

Comment: Apt rarely takes more than a minute or two to perform daily security upgrades, so this problem rarely occurs for most users. Interrupting apt while it is changing system-essential files (including files needed to resume from sleep!) may damage your system quite seriously. If apt is taking a very long time, that may be a symptom of a more serious problem that should be investigated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this depends. Since it's an upgrade I'd say once it has started installing the packages, then don't pause it.

But if it's still downloading, you can cancel it instead because re-running apt upgrade again will first check for cached packages then resume on the last not downloaded package...

Comment: You could re-word this answer to be clearer: "It's okay to pause upgrades that are *downloading*. However, once apt has completed downloading and has begun *installing packages*, do NOT interrupt the upgrade. You risk breaking your system quite badly. If you are not sure which step apt is working on, then do NOT interrupt it."

Comment: @user535733  Not used to commenting/giving answers. That's much much better. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A common method to pause a command is to press `Ctrl+z` in the terminal, in the window that launched the command. You'll have an indicator `Stopped` followed by the command you launched. 
Once you wish to continue, just type `fg` (foreground, meaning you want to bring the job to the foreground and continue it).

Caveats: if the command you pause includes network work, it's possible that pausing and starting from another network fails, as https operations are going, and changing your ip/location/... in the middle triggers warning from the network.
Second caveat: be careful when pausing a system update, it's never a good idea to interrupt an upgrade. It may, in certain cases, leave your system in a broken state. Always better to let it finish in one go.